# multiple representations of same entity being merged error with lazyload

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am trying to update N relation in 1:N relations ( primitive solution )

```
class Person{
// id etc.
   @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "owner", orphanRemoval=true)
   private List<Car> cars;
}

class Car{
// id etc.
    @ManyToOne
    private Person owner;
}
```

// get all persons and transform it into map

```
Map<id,Person> persons = personDAO.getALL().transformToMap();
// carprovider is entity from external db, it has all Car attributes and more.
List<CarProvider> cars = carDao.getAllFromProvider();

for( CarProvider car: cars ){
  if( persons.contains(car.getOwner().getId()){
   Person p = persons.get(car.getOwner().getId());
   List<Car> c = p.getCars();

   for( Car p_car: c ){
     if( p_car.getId() == car.getId() ) // match
       p_car.setDemage(car.getDemage());
   }
  }
}
personDAO.saveAll(persons.values())
```

Basicly i retrieve data from insuranceDB of newly dmged cars, i find if owner of that car exists in my DB, if yes, update its car.

However this throws:

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Multiple
>   representations of the same entity are being merged

As you can see i used LazyLoad, for that reason i also used:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true
```

I know this is bad practice and N+1 problem, however it still better than load all relations at once using EAGER, given fact i only do this task once a week.

I am using `CrudRepository`

Why is this happening? Havent met this error before and cant find any logical reasoning. How are multiple representations of same entity being merged?

This only happens when i use LazyLoad. The occurance of this error is bound to existence of entity in my DB. e.g

```
List<CarProvider> cars = carDao.getAllFromProvider();
```

also containts Car that i already have saved in my DB. So the entity itself will not update properties, but `saveAll()` will be called on same entity as it was retrieved via lazy load.

Thanks for help!

Comment: you could try to store in a collection just the modified p and then saveAll those.
Also check if the equals hashcode methods are correct

Comment: equals and hashcode should be correct, generated by IDE. The problem is, that  even with just saving modified collection it does not work.

Comment: i have compared every object and every object in its relation, neither of them are the same... i dont understand why is this error occuring...